# Linux kernel panic when I disable the console via cmdline?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot, buildroot

I currently have an embedded device booting via mainline U-Boot in to the mainline Linux kernel (built via Buildroot). This works fine and the board functions as intended.

One option I would like is the ability to disable the serial console from U-Boot so that I won't see any output once Linux has started booting. I'm trying to do this by setting the `bootargs` U-Boot environment variable as follows:

`setenv bootargs "console=null"`

I have also tried setting the `silent=1` and `silent_linux=1` variables.

When I set any of these options Linux boots, still outputting all messages as usual, and then kernel panics shortly in to the boot process:

```
Warning: unable to open an initial console.
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: init Tainted: G        W         5.1.9 #2
Call Trace:
[e4091e50] [c05d17f8] dump_stack+0x80/0xa0 (unreliable)
[e4091e60] [c00263dc] panic+0x134/0x2f0
[e4091ec0] [c0029a64] do_exit+0x4d0/0x92c
[e4091f10] [c0029f3c] do_group_exit+0x40/0xac
[e4091f30] [c0029fbc] __wake_up_parent+0x0/0x18
[e4091f40] [c000e1e0] ret_from_syscall+0x0/0x38
--- interrupt: c01 at 0xfde0b60
    LR = 0xfec340c
Rebooting in 180 seconds..
```

I assume I have configured the kernel incorrectly as it is both still outputting to the default serial port and it's panicking, but I'm not sure what would cause this to happen.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

## Un*x, Linux and `console=null`

On POSIX OS console is a requiremtent! Without console, the kernel panic! You may found possible values for `console=` in your [Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) in your distribution·

You could change *log level* with proc file:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Or by typing [Magic SysRq key](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

- Hold <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and keep them pressed.
- Hit <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> first, then release them, (while keeoping <kbd>AltGr</kbd> pressed), then
- Hit <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> ... and/or  <kbd>9</kbd>   (while keeoping <kbd>AltGr</kbd> pressed)

This will change log level to number corresponding to key pressed.

Comment: I understand a console is a requirement, however I should be able to redirect the console to `/dev/null` to not get any input. This should still enable the console but it should not output anything?

Comment: @Bak No, you currently cannot just "redirect" the kernel messages to `/dev/null`. Try adding a `loglevel=2` to the boot args.

Comment: "On POSIX OS console is a requiremtent!" [citation needed]

Comment: @Bak they actually recently tried to fix the "init crashes if no console -> panic" bug in Linux, but failed miserably, breaking a lot of systems. Search for "ttynull console" in recent lkml messages.